# CSS Effect like safari new tab

Tags: html, css

[image]

how to apply a effect like the photo below to image by using CSS or something else?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS 3d transforms. They aren't well supported right now, but they will work in Webkit browsers, including iOS.

I don't know of anyone who has tackled that example already (apart from the Safari team evidently!), but here is some recommended reading.

http://blog.persistent.info/2010/11/distortion-grid-using-css-3d-transforms.html

http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/